# How to get the file name using a returned URI

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm letting users pick a file from their device using:

```kotlin
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? -> ... }
```

I want to find out what is the name of the file they've picked. How can I retrieve the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a display name [via `DocumentFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile):

```kotlin
DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(uri).name
```

What the "display name" is will be up to the `DocumentsProvider` that the user is using. If the user is working with a filesystem-based provider, the display name probably is a filename.